# How to write a function in R

Tags: r, statistics

given a function

[image]

I'm not sure how to write this in R, I wrote it as:

[image]

But I'm getting this error:

[image: ti]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
#Function
f <-function(x) {4*x*exp(-2*x)}
#Integral
integrate(f,lower = 0,upper = Inf)
```

Comment: What about the "e" value?

Comment: @LearningMath899 In `R` e value is represented by `exp()` so you can use that for your functions!

Comment: @LearningMath899 You can also check `f <-function(x) {4*x*exp(1)^(-2*x)}` which has same goal as `f <-function(x) {4*x*exp(-2*x)}` but in last you use the build in function `exp` rather than using `exp(1)`!